# Learn how to design and implement large and complex applications using Lisp like languages

Tags: architecture, clojure, lisp, scheme

Instead of the traditional tutorials and books that mostly explain syntax, data structures, functions, high-order functions, macros, etc., and instead of the traditional project Euler like exercises, what are good comprehensive resources to learn how to design large applications in Lisp languages, covering client side as well as server side design and implementation?

Are there any guides out there, that explain from step 1 to step 42, how to incrementally implement an interesting application?

Comment: i haven't looked at it for some years, but i think norvig's old ai book (not the "modern" one) had some fairly large programs.  not huge, not not trivial either.

Comment: @Barney huuuhh... *making one*? Paths are made by walking! Furthermore, large and complex shouldn't excite you as much as substantial, correct and dense. See https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/compiler.clj

Comment: This question is a bit like asking: Is there a step-by-step guide to building the Taj Mahal, showing which brick goes where? The idea behind textbooks is to give you the tools to allow you to understand and construct large things. Perhaps you can elaborate on the failures that you see in existing texts? Sorry not to be more helpful....

Comment: John - there is a big gap between a book that explains how to stack bricks atop each other - explaining the fundamentals of bricks and stacking illustrated with toy problems - and a book that explains architecture, building science and project management - all skills you'd need to build the Taj Mahal without explicitly telling you how to build that one particular building. I think the OP wants to know about practical/applied architecture rather than brick fundamentals and toy problems.

Comment: I think _"framework"_ is the term you are looking for, like an MDI framework. Sorry the only success story I know off is Smalltalk's squeak.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question. There are a lot of OO/Design-books. Where are the FP-books on this subject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might like the book [Clojure in Action](http://www.manning.com/rathore/). It starts with an introduction to Clojure, goes on to discuss use cases where Clojure shines in "real world" software such as state management, concurrency, code generation and Java-interop, and then the book walks you through the development of a non-trivial, scalable web application that uses unit testing, custom DSLs, Hadoop, HBase and RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 6):

The best book IMHO to really *get* Scheme is [Structure and Interpretation
of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) (SICP).

Through the chapters, you'll implement progressively more complex systems - a numeric tower, a picture-manipulation language, a stream processor, concurrent programming, ... until finally, in the last two chapters, you end up writing several interpreters for different languages (Scheme itself, a logic language, ...), and a virtual machine and a compiler for Scheme.

The examples start slow and easy, and build on difficulty until you reach fairly large, complex and self-contained systems. It's the ultimate experience for really, really understanding how a programming language works and how to manage complexity and abstraction in your code. You'll be a better programmer after reading this book, I can assure you.

Sorry, no client-server applications in the book, but the systems developed will leave you ready to tackle fairly complex programming tasks in Scheme.

Answer (score 5):

See [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). Also, I think some of the Racket tutorials are pretty good: e.g., [building a web app](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html). That said, no tutorial or book is going to cover an example that is a full-featured application you could deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) describes a lot of useful patterns and approaches. Also take a look at [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/) and [Lisp Outside the Box](http://lisp-book.org/), which isn't finished, alas.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found [this book](http://norvig.com/paip.html) to be quite useful. It has an AI-centric approach oftentimes (as one would expect, given the title), but it also covers broader topics (especially PL stuff [compilers and interpreters specifically]), and it offers a deep understanding of common lisp.  As an alternative, I also like Graham's [On Lisp](http://paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) for 'esoteric' lispiness (advanced macros, some further exploration of PL-implementation stuff). And yeah, you can't go wrong with SICP. Happy hunting.